# Setting placeholder text for java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

As part of an assignment, I need to build a system shell simulator in Java. One of the features is to use the up arrow key (↑) to refer to history of commands run. I need to put 'placeholder' text in the console system input.

I understand how to store a history of the commands run. The part that I am not sure of is how to get the 'placeholder' text in the scanner input.

Example (user's input is in green):

[image]

When a user hits the up arrow key, they can get this (assuming `cal` was run prior):

[image]

Can this be accomplished using the `Scanner` system class? If not, can this be accomplished with something else?

Comment: You need to register a keylistener to capture uparrow. Also, you need to store the "history" of commands. Perhaps with an `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks, but I know that. I should have been more specific. I'm stuck on getting the history text into the scanner input.

Comment: Push it into the InputStream that the Scanner is reading from?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch could you elaborate a little further?

Comment: What's your requirements as far as keeping a buffer. IOW, does the screen need to be scrollable with all the history as well?

Answer (score 0):

Basically every time the user enters a command, you have to store that command, most likely as a `String` into some sort of `List`.

So...

```
ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
int displacementFromLastCommand = 0;
```

And every time the the scanner reads a line...

```
String newCommand = scanner.nextLine();
commands.add(newCommand);
displacementFromLastCommand = 0;
```

And then on your keyEvent...

```
public void onKeyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        displacementFromLastCommand ++;
        // set the current text to commands.get(commands.size() - dis);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will you also say how to attach a `KeyListener` to Eclipse's console or the terminal?

Comment: touché... I didn't realize he was using the native console. I thought he was creating his own in a jframe, but I didn't look at the screenshots close enough.

Comment: @tambykojak Thanks for that, but what I'm stuck on is: "set the current text to `commands.get(commands.size() - dis);`"

Comment: @josh, are you saying that you're able to register some sort of KeyEvent to the console?